# Un able to do pod setup after installing cocoapods

Tags: rubygems, cocoapods

I have installed cocoa pods and when i do

pod setup

i get following error

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- active_support/core_ext/string/strip (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.32.1/lib/cocoapods.rb:7
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.32.1/bin/pod:32
    from /usr/bin/pod:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/pod:19
```

Do i need to install active_support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old question, but valid answer: Yes.

Run `gem install activesupport` (no underscore between `active` and `support`) and see if your problem is resolved.